# Is it safe to use Direct ip to a printer that is already managed by Windows print server?

Tags: network-printer

There's a customer to which we connect using VPN. They don't have reverse access to our network. We need to connect to their server with remote desktop and print documents on our office printer.

Current solution is remote ssh forward of ports 515 and 9100. It works, the question is how safe it is.

Here we do:

```
ssh root@10.2.1.1 -R 0.0.0.0:9100:192.168.1.70:9100 -R 0.0.0.0:515:192.168.1.70:515
```

There we use windows standard tcp port IP_10.2.1.1 for the printer.

Comment: Can you define "safe"? If you're tunneling the print jobs, they're protected in-flight. But as you're running the print job from a server which they control, they could be doing anything, including capturing the print jobs direct from the local spooler.

Comment: Can queues interfere? Can they hack our printer (get stats for example)?

Comment: If you're connecting to their server via RDP why don't you use Printer Redirection to print your documents?

Comment: @joeqwerty Because of bugs in 1C: have to restart client to use new printer

Comment: Bugs in 1C:? I don't understand.